# Why 'return' does not break a loop nested in function?

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to use a loop nested in function. Why the condition is not breaking the loop with 'return' in the function and goes to to end still printing "Incremental"?

```
x = 1
def function(x):
    if x == 4:
        return print("END")

    for x in range (1,8):
        x += 1
        print("Incremental")
        if x == 4:
            print("Condition met")
            function(x)

function(x)
```

From terminal I have following output:

Incremental

Incremental

Incremental

Condition met

END

Incremental

Incremental

Incremental

Incremental

EDIT: The idead behind this task (production scheduling), was that i was iterating thorugh days of the week (1st loop - in this case n=1 means Monday) and  manufactured products (2nd loop). Sometimes i need to break the first loop first, without breaking the 2nd, because i don't want to change the product, i want to change the day of the production.

Comment: `return` returns from the *current* function call, not all the function calls.

Comment: So how to break from whole funtion, not current?

Comment: You could put a `return` in the second `if x==4:` block.

Comment: Because `return` only returns by one level of recursion, not by multiple levels. If you want to jump out of an arbitrarily deep call stack, `raise` an exception and catch it around the outermost call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is, in the code you call `function(x)` again when `x==4`. If you still want to use recursion in the code (I am not sure the reason behind it) following code will work:

```
x = 1
def function(x):
    if x == 4:
        return print("END")

    for x in range (1,8):
        x += 1
        print("Incremental")
        if x == 4:
            print("Condition met")
            function(x)
            break

function(x)
```

Comment: That answer solved my problem. Thank you. I have clarified my question in EDIT part in my main post.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing your function will never do what you are expecting it to do;

When you call function inside of your loop, you are making a recursive call to the function, and since you are passing 4 to it, it returns `print("END")` to where you are calling it from (when you make a recursive call, you are in the context of the function you called).

TL;DR: your return statement returns from another function that gets added to the stack when you call it; So it will never break the loop.

If you wanna break there is no need to do it recursively!

this will do it

```py
x = 1
def function(x):

    for x in range (1,8):
        x += 1
        print("Incremental")
        if x == 4:
            print("Condition met")
            break # or return

function(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You print "Incremental" 4 more times after "End" because when `x == 4` you call the `function(x)` again inside the conditional in a a recursive manner. At `x == 4` you go again into the `function(x)` where you print "End" and return back to the for loop and continue till the loop terminates during which "Incremental" is printed 4 more times.

An improved version of this function can be written as follows,

```
def function(x):
    for x in range (1,8):
        print("Incremental")
        if x == 4:
            print("Condition met")
            print("End")
            break

function(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the solution, which i was looking for i guess.